# How should we do nginx reverse proxy configuration for spring boot docker applications?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two spring boot applications and nginx web server. These applications work with docker-compose. I want to run my applications in 9000, 9001, 9002 ports respectively. (nginx -> 9000, spring-boot-app1 -> 9001, spring-boot-app2 -> 9002)

spring-app1 should be accessible from the browser at http://localhost:9000/ and spring-app2 should be accessible from the browser at http://localhost:9000/ui

According to this, how to configuration nginx?

**Project Folder Structure**

```
|── ...
│
│── nginx                    
│   ├── default.conf          
│   ├── Dockerfile   
│
├── web-static                    
│   ├── src          
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── Dockerfile 
│
├── web-ui                    
│   ├── src          
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── Dockerfile 
│
├── docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    build: ./nginx
    image: proxy
    ports:
        - "9000:80"

  service1:
    container_name: service1
    build: ./web-static
    image: service1
    ports:
        - "9001:9000"

  service2:
    container_name: service2
    build: ./web-ui
    image: service2
    ports:
        - "9002:9000"
```

**nginx.conf file**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://service1:9000;
    }

    location  /ui {
      proxy_pass http://service2:9000/;
    }        
}
```

I made some changes to the Nginx configuration file. However, css, image files and request don't work correctly and don't displayed.
Example request : My request "localhost:9000/ui/?form". But localhost:9000 answering to request. I don't want this.

1. Briefly, I want spring-boot-app1 should be accessible from the browser at localhost:9000/
2. spring-boot-app2 should be accessible from the browser at localhost:9000/ui/
3. I want it to work independently in itself.

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you find the solution?